# How to apply a ON DELETE CASCADE on 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0

This is the table structure:

```
create table father (
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    `id` INT UNSIGNED
);

create table mother (
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    `id` INT UNSIGNED
);

create table son (
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    `id`      INT     UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `father`  INT     UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `mother`  INT     UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (`father`)
    REFERENCES `father` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (`mother`)
    REFERENCES `mother` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO father (id) values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO mother (id) values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO son values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1), 
                       (4, 2, 2), (5, 2, 2), (6, 2, 2);
```

If I run a command as

```
delete from father where id = 2;
```

I'm expected to delete all `son` values that have a `father = 2`, but it doesn't work as I wish. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Thanks to @P.Salmon I have solved with:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Code works as expected - father is deleted sons are deleted - are you somehow expecting mother to be deleted? or something else?

Comment: No, I want sons deleted, but for me, doesn't work: 

`mysql> delete from father where id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)`

I have 1 only row affected :/ I don't know why... The mysql version is: `8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3`

Comment: Code behaves as expected https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45ac57bb617db77953f9e5bcc2ade3d6 1 row affected refers to the row deleted from father - deleted son rows do not show in affected count - is that a problem for you?.

Comment: On my PC doesn't delete the son's rows. How can I see if I have a "strange" settings on mysql?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue by SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = OFF; , I thought this was only ever temporary.. show variables like 'foreign%'; to check.

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you very much!!!

Comment: You could publish your resolution as an answer to help others.

Comment: When FKs and Triggers get too complex, write a Stored Procedure to encapsulate the tasks; then `CALL` that.